# SOLVED: Compiling PHP with GD : relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `WebPMemoryWrite' can not be used when making a shared object;

Tags: php, linux, compilation, gd

I'm currently installing PHP with GD library from sources on a RedHat7 server and I'm facing some issues.

I configure PHP with this command:

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/server/lib/httpd/bin/apxs --with-pdo-mysql --with-config-file-path=/server/php-7.3.9/conf --with-libxml-dir=/server/lib/libxml2 --with-curl=/server/lib/curl --with-gd --enable-mbstring --with-jpeg-dir=/server/lib/libjpeg --with-png-dir=/server/lib/libpng –with-webp-dir=/server/lib/webp
```

It works but when I'm doing the make command I have this error:

```
/bin/ld: /server/lib/webp/lib/libwebp.a(picture_enc.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `WebPMemoryWrite' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [libphp7.la] Error 1
```

I also tried to compile and install it without webp (It's not required in the PHP documentation: [php doc](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/image.installation.php)) but I have this error :

```
ext/gd/libgd/.libs/gd_webp.o: In function `gdImageCreateFromWebpCtx':
/server/php-7.3.9/ext/gd/libgd/gd_webp.c:68: undefined reference to `WebPGetInfo'
/sever/php-7.3.9/ext/gd/libgd/gd_webp.c:79: undefined reference to `WebPDecodeARGB'
ext/gd/libgd/.libs/gd_webp.o: In function `gdImageWebpCtx':
/server/php-7.3.9/ext/gd/libgd/gd_webp.c:153: undefined reference to `WebPEncodeRGBA'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
```

So it seems to be required.
Can you please help me to solve this
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by replacing my installation of webp package.
At first I used the pre-compiled linux package and replacing it by native sources and a compiling, make & make install solve the problem.

Thanks all